# Forcing OpenID login instead of Drupal own authentication

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

Is there a way to force the users to use OpenID (e.g. Google, Facebook, Twitter) and not use Drupal's internal authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I simple solution would be to [alter the login form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to remove the username and password fields.

Here is some sample code to get you started:

```
/**
 * Alter the login form page
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  _MYMODULE_alter_login_form($form);
}

/**
 * Alter the login form block
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  _MYMODULE_alter_login_form($form);
}

/**
 * Function to change a bunch of things in the user_login form (both the block
 * and login screen).
 */
function _MYMODULE_alter_login_form(&$form) {
  unset($form['name']);
  unset($form['pass']);
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know of any contrib modules that will do this for you; the good news is that I have wrote 95% of the module for you. ;)

Comment: I don't know that much about Drupal nor PHP, so I don't really want to alter login form, is there a way to do it using something out of the box?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell, but I have written most of the code for you ;)

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/41753/39617