# specify $form elements to be excluded from display?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms, theming

I want to hide certain elements in form using form_alter or a template file. I have read somewhere that in Drupal 7 , we can specify $form elements so it will not display in form, but I can't remember!
Not unset() but some other function!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using `unset()` isn't a good solution for forms (as I think you know), as you never know what submit/validate handlers might be expecting the unset element to exist when they're processed. This can lead to unwanted errors.

There are three methods you can safely use to 'hide' a form element

- Use `'#type' => 'value'` on the element, which will have the effect that the value for the element will still be passed through to the submit/validate functions with its `#value` as normal. This is my preferred method.
- Use `'#access' => FALSE` on the element to denote it should not be outputted to the screen.
- Use `'#type' => 'hidden'` as Bart has suggested (although use of this depends on your use case; I imagine if you're trying to hide the value of a form element you don't want to output it in the form as a hidden input).

Comment: forgot [hide()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/hide/7) .

Comment: @zhilevan `hide()` shouldn't be used on form elements, it can easily mess the whole form submission process up as validators are still run for the element. For example, if you `hide($form['title']);` on a node form you won't ever be able to submit the form, as the title field is required, but a value won't be provided. The 3 methods above are the best ones to use, in that order :)

Comment: @Clive thanks, i know above methods, my question was something related to hide() i think(still cant remember the function).. anyway please refer my comment in 1st answer, why `drupal_render($form['base']['prices']['sell_price'])` is not working?

Comment: Is that code in a template file that's theming the form? If not, the reason it's not working is that while you can print out any render element to the screen with `drupal_render()`, you won't get any of the form tags/tokens/etc. unless you output the whole `$form` array

Comment: i used hook theme and print_r($form) and even drupal_render($form['title']) are working , the problem is the elements under vertcal tabs!

Comment: will display form , but its not saving

Comment: If you're using a theme function have you added `$output .= drupal_render_children($form);`, or if a template file have you added `print drupal_render_children($form)` at the bottom?

Comment: @Clive already done that, i told you i can save title and body , but not sell price (which comes under vertical tabs)!

Comment: It would be good to see your whole code, are you able to post it?

Comment: @Clive updated the question with code

Comment: Cool. As a test, try changing the last of those 4 calls to `drupal_render($form['base']['prices']);`, and then `drupal_render($form['base']);`. I know it's not what you want to do exactly, but if the form submits correctly with either of those methods you know there's something contained in one of the outer arrays that the submit handler needs to be processed properly

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a template file you can hide stuff using [hide()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7).

If you want to hide a form element in `hook_form_alter`, `unset()` might be your best option.

If it's just to store a value you could use ['#type' => 'hidden'](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#hidden) as well.

Comment: hide is better method to exluce of element.

Comment: What I was trying to achieve was a custom Ubsercart product node form, all I wanted to display is sell_price, and hide other elements like shipping, weight etc. But `drupal_render($form['base']['prices']['sell_price'])` will display form , but its not saving!

Answer (score 4):

I've found using #access to false can break some forms if used on submit buttons or similar. 
In those cases i've just used CSS to hide elements:

```
$form['basic']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'element-hidden';
```

Just another option.