# how to effectively hide a field (with title) on a form

Tags: 7, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [specify $form elements to be excluded from display?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41748/specify-form-elements-to-be-excluded-from-display)

I would like to hide a field on a form using `hook_form_ID_alter`. The form is owned by another module. This field cannot be `unset` because it contains a value.

Using CSS `{display: none}` for the standard field class is not good because the field should be hidden only in specific conditions (which must be determined using php).

In `hook_form_ID_alter`, I could add an `#attribute` to the field with a class value e.g. `hideme` and then use CSS to hide this class. But it will leave the field title (tried).

The field has `#prefix` set to `<div class='some_class'>` (in this particular case). This prefix precedes the field as well as the title when displayed in a browser. So I could analyze the prefix with regular expression and add a `hideme` class there. But I am not 100% sure what the #prefix will contain, so the regexp could be complex.

Perhaps there is a better way to hide a field with title on a form?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [#access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access) property for the form field to `FALSE`. The form field will not be shown to the users, but its value will be still be available in `$form_state['values']` for the submission, and validation handlers.

Using #access is always the suggested way to avoid users can change the value of a form field, and avoid any third-party module depending on that form field starts to raise warnings, or fails to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`hide()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7) function instead of [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php), if you want to retain the value in the field. From [the docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7):

> Hides an element from later rendering.

In simple words, `hide()` marks the render-able array as already rendered, so that the theme's function will not render it.

Comment: `hide()` shouldn't be used for form elements, it can cause a lot of problems. See the comments on the accepted answer to the duplicate question :)