# How do I display only nested form elements in modal

Tags: 8, ajax, forms

i'm currently working on a custom field/widget.

For a better ux i want to display some nested elements in a modal dialog.
The elements are generated during form submission (multistep widget) i added a custom ajax callback like this: (For better understanding i reduced the code)

```
public static function myAjaxCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $response->setAttachments($form['#attached']);

      $button = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
      $element = NestedArray::getValue($form, array_slice($button['#array_parents'], 0, -3));

      $response->addCommand(
        new OpenModalDialogCommand('Only a few sub elements', $element, [])
      );

      return $response;
}
```

The problem in this function is the elements are, obviously, rendered without a form around and so they can't get submitted.

Which would be the correct way to display only some nested elements in an ajax dialog?

Best regards
Michael

Comment: You could hide the unwanted form elements, see here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41748/specify-form-elements-to-be-excluded-from-display (this is still the same in D8)

Comment: The problem is they are nested in multiple dragndrop containers. In this case this won't work.

Thanks anyway!